# Printing linked list always prints last node

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I am currently  working on a project in which I need to add a Node at the end of a linked list (which should be easy nut is driving me nuts). The problem is that when I try to print the full linked list I get the data of the last node repeatedly.
My code:

```
struct page *add_page (struct page *web, char *url){
    struct page *newNode = (struct page*) malloc(1*sizeof(struct page));
    newNode->url = url;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    
    if(web == NULL){
        web = newNode;
    }else{
        struct page *curr = web;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            if(newNode->url==curr->url){
                printf("URL \"%s\" is already on the web\n",newNode->url);
                return web;
                free(newNode);
            }else{
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
        curr->next = newNode;
    }
    return web;
    free(newNode);
}
```

I am sure that the problem is on this function. I have tried other ways but this is the best I could get.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please enable warnings in your compiler. You should get some warning about unreachable code after `return`. Also you assign `newNode` to some other node's `next` pointer. You mustn't free it as it will be used when traversing the list.

Comment: If you want to prevent same values to be enqueue in your list, you should check first before allocating memory for a new node. You cause a memory leak in case you find the same url. Also you might think about using `strcmp` to check for same url.

Comment: How do you call that function? Where does `url` point to? How do you initialize your list? How do you print your list? Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Without sufficient information I would guess you only use one buffer for `url` and as you do not copy into a new buffer but just assign a pointer, all nodes will point to that one and only buffer.

Comment: You don't make a copy of the URL so the onus is on the calling code to use a different buffer each time the function is called.  You should probably allocate a copy of the URL, remembering that it will need to be freed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the same char pointer in your multiple calls `add_page` and only change the *content* that it points to to between calls. This means that you only have one char pointer, which is getting shared by all nodes you create. Any change to the string stored there, will be the string that all nodes point to.

You should either change the calling code, so that it creates a new string instead of mutating the existing one, or else make sure that the function takes a *copy* of the provided `url` string. Since you did not provide the calling code, I'll go for the second solution.

Some other issues:

- you should not compare char pointers to detect a duplicate node, but compare the string contents using `strcmp`.
- You have dead code following your `return` statements. In the first case, the `free` call should happen *before* the `return` statement. The final `free` however makes no sense in this function. That should happen later, at a moment you want to remove a node or the whole tree, not in this function.

```
struct page *add_page (struct page *web, char *url) {
    struct page *newNode = (struct page*) malloc(1*sizeof(struct page));
    // Store a copy of the url string:
    newNode->url = (char *) malloc(strlen(url)+1);
    strcpy(newNode->url, str);

    newNode->next = NULL;
    
    if (web == NULL) {
        web = newNode;
    } else {
        struct page *curr = web;
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            // Compare the contents of the two strings
            if (strcmp(newNode->url, curr->url) == 0) {
                printf("URL \"%s\" is already on the web\n", newNode->url);
                // Free both the copied url and the new node itself
                free(newNode->url);
                free(newNode);
                // ...and only then return
                return web;
            } else {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
        curr->next = newNode;
    }
    return web;
    // Remove dead code after this `return`
}
```

Don't forget to properly free the url before freeing the node whenever you need to remove a node.